How did beef come to be commonly eaten in Kerala (even among Hindus)?
Times of India ("Why Kerala has No Beef with Beef", [2015][1]):

It [beef] accounts for more than 40% of all meat consumed in the state. Around 80% of the people here regularly eat beef, not just in Christian and Muslim homes, and not just the rich either. There are no precise figures, but there is enough anecdotal evidence to suggest that more Hindus could be eating it regularly than Christians and Muslims put together.

Vice ("The Indian State Where Everyone Eats Beef", [2016][2]):

eating beef is not only legal and accepted, but also an important cultural tradition. ...
There’s even a saying in some parts of Kerala that goes, “A Nasrani meal is not complete without beef fry”

Manoj Nair (a Kerala chef quoted by BBC, "The Indian state that is obsessed with beef fry", [2016][3]):

Beef is very important for Kerala. There can be a Hindu, Muslim and Christian sitting at one table and they'd bond over a plate of beef fry and parantha despite any differences of caste and class


In a country whose Hindus generally regard cows as sacred, how did Kerala come to be the exception? How did beef come to be commonly eaten in Kerala (even among Hindus)?
One explanation given by Times of India is this:

Of course, cultural osmosis has had a major role to play in this. Muslims, Christians and Hindus in Kerala have coexisted fraternally.

But I don't find this explanation too convincing. Did Muslims, Christians and Hindus not "coexist fraternally" in other states? Was there much more "fraternal coexistence" in Kerala than other states? Even so, how would such "fraternal coexistence" lead to Hindus in Kerala violating an ancient and inviolable taboo?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Please ask questions about scope in meta; I'm going to revert your edit because the new content is not relevant to the question - it is relevant to open/close/moderation/site procedures.
